# Whats the difference between $(elements).not() and $(elements).filter()

Tags: jquery

Just out of interest is there any major advantages/disadvantages of using either?

Straight from the docs it says:

1. `not()` = Remove elements from the set of matched elements.
2. `filter()`= Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match
       the selector or pass the function's test.

E.g when I pass a function they both have the same result? Which would be best in this situation?

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    $("tr").hide().filter(function(index){
        return ($(this).data("foo") == val || val == 0);
    }).show();
});
```

Comment: From a performance point of view which is best?

Comment: .filter(), check it here: http://jsperf.com/comparing-jquery-s-filter-vs-not and run the test

Comment: @kidz Are you sure about that? I'd say that the test was flawed because they were not minimal pairs, try this modified version: http://jsperf.com/comparing-jquery-s-filter-vs-not/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is just syntactic approach.

Using `not()`, you specify what you **don't** want; using `filter()` you specify what you **do** want.

Comment: Agreed, [demo with `not()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5RFHU/1/), and a [demo with `filter()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5RFHU/2/).

Answer (score 2):

`filter()`=>A string containing a selector expression to match the current set of elements against.

`not()` =>All selectors are accepted inside :not(), for example: :not(div a) and :not(div,a).

according the performance point of view filter is faster

`filter()` >> `not()`